# Errors in Visual Studio 2019 when im trying to make a dll file

Tags: dll

I would like to create a dll hack for a game and just selected dynamic link library and already have 3 errors.

This is the original code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Errors:

```
cannot open source file "windows.h" ;
expected a ';' ;
identifier "BOOL" is undefined
```

Comment: Okay great. So what do you want us to do about it? Do you need help fixing the error? Do you want to know why it happens? What do you want us to do. Just saying it's a hack and you have done x,y,z and here is an error is not really a question. It's just information. Please explicitly state what you are actually wanting us to do with this question. Additionally if you state what game then it might be found that it's an access restriction of the game to stop dll hacks. Please read [ask]

Comment: i want to fix them